# reading variable number of columns with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to read a variable number of columns from my input file ( the number of columns is defined by the user, there's no limitation ). For every column I have multiple variables to read, three in my case, set by the user as well.

So the file to read is like:

```
2   3   5
6   7   9
3   6   8
```

In Fortran this is really easy to do:

```
DO 180 I=1,NMOD
READ(10,*) QARR(I),RARR(I),WARR(I)
```

NMOD is defined by the user, as well as all the values in the example. All of them are input parameters to be stored in memory. By doing these I can save all the variables I need and I can use it whenever I want, recalling them by changing the I index. How can I obtain the same result with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example file 'text'

```
2 3 5
6 7 9
3 6 8
```

---

Python code

```
data = []

with open('text') as file:
    columns_to_read = 1  # here you tell how many columns you want to read per line
    for line in file:
        data.append(list(map(int, line.split()[:columns_to_read])))

print(data)  # print: [[2], [6], [3]]
```

`data` will hold an array of arrays that represent your lines.

Comment: Two questions:
1) How can I recall the variables I need ? If I need just some of them how can i select those?
2) I need the script to read a number of columns dependent on NMOD. I have also other stuff in the file and I don't want to read it all. Is it doable?
Many thanks.

Comment: You can do: `data[x][y]`, where `x`=number of the line and `y`=column. So,  `data[2][2]` would retrieve the number `8`, last line and last number in this case.

Comment: If you have other data in the file that needs to be ignored, you should update your question with a proper example of the file, so people will take this into consideration when providing the code.

Comment: The Fortran code reads a NMOD number of columns, maybe I wasn't clear enough, I'm sorry. It is possible to do that just by slightly changing your code?

Comment: @GiacomoM if my answer responds your question correctly, please, don't forget to mark as 'best answer'.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice
with open('file.txt', 'rt') as f:
    # default slice from row 0 until end with step 1
    # example islice(10, 20, 2) take only row 10,12,14,16,18
    dat = islice(f, 0, None, 1)  
    column = None # change column here, default to all

    # this keep the list value as string 
    # mylist = [i.split() for i in dat]
    # this keep the list value as int
    mylist = [[int(j) for j for i.split()[:column] for i in dat]
```

Code above construct 2d list

access with mylist[row][column]

Example - mylist[2][3] access row 2 column 3

**Edit** : improve code efficiency with @Guillaume @Javier suggestion

Comment: I would open the file as a text file, (explicitly specifying mode 'rt' on open()) then use readlines().

Comment: @Guillaume thanks, edit the answer to use readlines(), i was thinking of the newline but its redundant since the split() should already take care that. For the 'rt' mode, i think its fine since its default with twxt read mode

Comment: realines() adds nothing and raises used memory. Without that method call the same code is better.

Comment: ah yes true, iterating over f directly is better, it will read the file line by line anyway :)

Comment: @Javier you are correct since i don need whole files in memory, change my answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks to everyone guys!